# Execute an external BLAST program in PHP

Tags: php, exec, bioinformatics, centos7, blast

I want to execute a blastx search application in PHP instead of Linux console text terminal.

The actual command line arguments would be ([see definition of refer](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK279675/)):

```
./blastx -query $input -db ${Sbjct}_db -evalue 0.0001 -outfmt 6 -out /path/to/output.tsv
```

Here's my PHP partial code.

```
exec('
/path/to/blastx 
-query /path/to/PAO1.fasta 
-db /path/to/VFDB_setB_pro
-evalue 0.0001
-outfmt 6
-out /path/to/output.tsv
');
```

However, when I call `exec()` function in PHP program there is nothing happened.

I also tried another method. It return error code 1. Here is my php `exec()` content:

```
exec('sh /path/to/myscript.sh', $output, $return_var);
```

What vital steps I missed out? 
Is there any alternative method to execute external programs?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The break lines are the problem, try

```
<?php

exec('\
/path/to/blastx \
-query /path/to/PAO1.fasta \
-db /path/to/VFDB_setB_pro \
-evalue 0.0001 \
outfmt 6 \
-out /path/to/output.tsv \
');
```

**EDIT**

I show the process since I cann't do tracking

1- Input data

> cat seq.fa #NUCLEOTIDES

```
>seq_1
GGCAGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAACGGTAACAGGAAGCAGCTTGCTGCTTTGCT
GACGAGTGGCGGACGGGTGAGTAATGTCTGGGAAACTGCCTGATGGAGGGGGAT
AACTACTGGAAACGGTAGCTAATACCGCATAATGTCGCAAGACCAAAGAGGGGGA
```

> cat database.fa #PROTEINS

```
>KDG85104.1 hypothetical protein AE17_03267, partial [Escherichia coli UCI 58]
PVVIPLHQAVSQTLLTRPPLVSKAASCFLLPFDLHVLGLPPAFNLSHDQTLQFKSLMLKELNFVMNYVFTLETWYSFFVL
RR
>EUM99718.1 hypothetical protein L347_09473, partial [Enterobacter sp. MGH 1]
VVIPLHQAVSQTLLTRPPLVSEAASCFLLPFDLHVLGLPPAFNLSHDQTLQFKSLMLNELNFVMNYVFTR
>CSD41531.1 Uncharacterised protein [Vibrio cholerae]
MADHPLRPARDRRLGEPLPHQLANPTWAYPVAQGPKVPCFALARLCGISHRFQWLSPSTGQFPRHYSPVRRSPPKEQVPL
CCRSTCMC
```

2- Format database

```
makeblastdb -in database.fa -dbtype prot -out database
```

3- bash script

> cat myscript.sh

```
path_to_blast/blastx -query path_to_query/seq.fa -db path_to_db/database -evalue 0.0001 -outfmt 6
```

4- php script

> cat blast.php

```
<?php
exec('sh myscript.sh', $output, $return_var);
print_r($output);
echo "$return_var\n";
```

5- Run it,

```
php blast.php
```

you get,

```
Array
(
    [0] => seq_1    KDG85104.1  100.00  38  0   0   118 5   1   38  1e-24   77.0
    [1] => seq_1    EUM99718.1  97.30   37  1   0   115 5   1   37  2e-23   73.6
    [2] => seq_1    CSD41531.1  70.59   51  15  0   162 10  38  88  1e-22   72.0
)
0
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. The situation is the same. 
No `nohup.out` file was created.

Comment: To make things clear, I try to run this command:
 `exec('string $command', $output, $return_var);`
The `return_var` argument always returned 127 and `output` is empty.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works perfect now. I guess this is permission denied. I using `visudo` to edit sudoers file, `apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

Comment: @Yi-TingLiu Is another question, I am not an expert on unix permissions