# Aborting AJAX request in long polling function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bioinformatics, long-polling

I'm implementing an application which can be able to monitor background jobs ([BLAST program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42293968/execute-an-external-blast-program-in-php)).

I wish that when PID equal 0, then stop the polling process.

But in my long-polling example, the polling process continues to run even use `abort()` function.

This solution is not working for me.

```
var poll_xhr;

    (function doPoll() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            poll_xhr = $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'longpoll.php',
                error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    displayError();
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    if (result == 0) {

                        // To kill the AJAX request (Not Working)
                        console.log("The process is not running.");
                        poll_xhr.abort();
                    }
                    else 
                        console.log(result);        
                },
                dataType: "json",
                complete: doPoll,
                timeout: 5000
            });
        })
    })();
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
    $pid = $_SESSION['PID'];

    if(file_exists('/proc/'. $pid)){
        // $pid is running
        echo json_encode($pid);
    }
    else{ 
        $e = 0;
        echo json_encode($e); 
    }
```

How can I cancel the polling process? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling `doPoll` on `complete` means it *always* will be called, whatever the result and the state of the xhr.

From your requirements, you should call `doPoll` from the `success`handler, when the result says "job is still running"

Answer (score 0):

try to use "clearTimeout()"
and don't use "complete".

```
var poll_xhr;

(function doPoll() {
    var time=setTimeout(function() {
        poll_xhr = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'break.php',
            error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //displayError();
                console.log(request, textStatus, errorThrown);
            },
            success: function(result) {
                if (result == 0) {

                    // To kill the AJAX request (Not Working)
                    console.log("The process is not running.");
                    //poll_xhr.abort();
                    clearTimeout(time);
                }
                else {
                    console.log(result);   
                    doPoll     
                }
            },
            dataType: "json",
            //complete: doPoll,
            timeout: 5000
        });
    })
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the above method cannot display log messages in `real time`, it must refresh the page to see it's already done.